# Quantum statistical mechanics formalism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, computational-physics

How do we solve a Hamiltonian written in second quantization by using quantum statistical formalism? For example, the following Hamiltonian

$$H = \sum_{i=1}^L c_{i+1}^\dagger c_i + h.c.$$

I have solved few examples in which $H$ had some function form but I am not sure how to find ground-state properties of Hamiltonian wirrten in second quantization. Especially, how do we solve this kind of Hamiltonian in computer? i.e. by using exact diagonalization (for small system sizes)

I am sorry of this question seems stupid. I couldn't find any article which explain things like this.

Answer (score 1):

You should find the answer to your question in any basic reference which deals with the tight-binding model. You introduce the Fourier transforms of the annihilation and creation operaors. This diagonalizes the Hamiltonian in $k$-space. The energy associated to $k$ is the Fourier transform of the hoppings (1 in your case, in 1D, so just a cosine). See similar question here [Dispersion relation in tight binding model with even indices only](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/396929/dispersion-relation-in-tight-binding-model-with-even-indices-only?rq=1)

Comment: thank you for your reply, but this does not answer my question. I want to understand the formalism of quantum statistical mechanics. How do we find the partition function and average values of various operators?

Comment: @SanaUllah After you find the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian, partition function could be evaluated according to the principles of Statitical Mechanics. They are completely general and cover all the Hamiltonians.